# Error on Calling Array as parameter VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

ok first of all i have 1 array here

```
  Dim JD = {"0", "LIE"}
```

then i have 3 textboxes that i put in array too

```
  Dim ColJD1 As TextBox() = {Me.JD1_1, Me.JD1_2, Me.JD1_3}
```

then i use those arrays in a subroutine :

```
     Sub fillword(ByVal num1, ByVal qtychar, ByVal num2, ByVal i, ByVal Coltxtbox)

     If Strings.Mid(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("SAVE.txt"), Strings.InStr(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("SAVE.txt"), num1), qtychar) = num2 & ".True" Then

        For test = 1 To Strings.Len(JD(i))
            For Each txtbox In Coltxtbox
                Dim a As String = Strings.Mid(JD(i), test, 1)
                MsgBox(a)
                txtbox.Text = i     => here is the problem
                i = i + 1
            Next
        Next
    End If

  End Sub

   Sub loadgame1()
      fillword("1", 6, "1", 1, ColJD1)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button_click bla bla 
      loadgame1()
   End Sub
```

It's throwing error :
"Object variable or With block variable not set."

any kind of help is greatly appreciated

@w0051977 actually the variable name is "test" and not "uji"

After receiving Hans suggestion i did modify the code but it still throws error :
i changed the code :

```
    Dim JD = {"0", "RIA"}
    Dim ColJD1 As TextBox()

    Sub fillarray()
     InitializeComponent()
        ColJD1 = {JD1_1, JD1_2, JD1_3}
    End Sub

     Sub fillword(ByVal num1, ByVal qtychar, ByVal num2, ByVal i, ByVal Coltxtbox)
     fillarray()
      If Strings.Mid(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("SAVE.txt"), Strings.InStr(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("SAVE.txt"), num1), qtychar) = num2 & ".True" Then
       For test = 1 To Strings.Len(JD(i))
               For Each txtbox In Coltxtbox => Now the problem moves here , it throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
                  Dim a As String = Strings.Mid(JD(i), test, 1)
                  MsgBox(a)
                  txtbox.Text = i     
                  i = i + 1
               Next
            Next
         End If
      End Sub

      Sub loadgame1()
         fillword("1", 6, "1", 1, ColJD1)
      End Sub

      Private Sub Button_click bla bla 
        loadgame1()
      End Sub
```

Comment: What is the variable: uji for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the debugger, you can inspect the variables to find the one that is Nothing.

Which is pretty likely to be the `ColJD1` array, can't see the scope to make the call but it is very common mistake.  Members like Me.JD1_1 don't get a value until *after* the InitializeComponent() method runs.  The variable is getting initialized too soon, *before* that method runs.  So it will just contain elements that are Nothing.  You need to write it like this instead:

```
Dim ColJD1 As TextBox()

Public Sub New
    InitializeComponent()
    ColJD1 = {Me.JD1_1, Me.JD1_2, Me.JD1_3}
End Sub
```

Where Sub New is the constructor that needs to be added.

Comment: Dear sir , it still throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", i'm still clueless where should I add "New" on the array declaration

Comment: ok disregard my last comment, the code works like a  charm, thank you @Hans Passant